# In the Outlook Add-In API for javascript in a Compose Form, is it possible to require a Read Receipt on a message before it's sent?

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to find out if it's possible from an Outlook Add-In for a Compose Form to add a Read Receipt to a message before it's sent.
My company has a form library built in an older version of outlook and an older version of exchange.  The form has quite a few fields that are easy to replicate with an outlook add-in.  The main requirement that I haven't been able to find any documentation on is that each time the form is used to send a message, it automatically checks the Options/Tracking/Send Read Receipt checkbox before the form creates the email body and sends the message.
 I've read through the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/), but I haven't been able to find anything that mentions Tracking or Read Receipts.  Is that something I'd have to call in Exchange Web Services or access through the REST API?  All of the messages sent with this add-in will be going to recipients inside my company.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Read Receipt feature is not a part of the Outlook Add-Ins framework. We track Outlook Add-In feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) are considered when we go through our planning process. Alternatively, you may be able to use the [Outlook REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api) to achieve this.